# Getting the 5 most recent dates in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, max, ssms

I am trying to get 5 most recent dates for a query I am working on. Basically the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th largest dates. So far query just is a  group by the max date. Here is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT
    Customer,
    Plant,
    ForecastDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Customer, Plant ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC ) AS ROW_NUM 
        FROM
            table
    ) AS T
WHERE
    ROW_NUM = 1
```

Here is the output of the query code above:

[image: Output]

This is in Microsoft sql server management studio 18

Comment: what do you mean by  largest dates ?

Comment: So just wrap that query in `SELECT TOP 5 ForecastDate FROM $query ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

You first sort the result set and then take the 5 highest

```
SELECT TOP 5 Customer, Plant, ForecastDate FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Plant ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC) as ROW_NUM 
FROM table
) AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC
```